# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pony.orm.dbproviders'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, data-binding, ponyorm

I got this err when I converted the program to .exe when it was .py, there was no problem.

```
   db.bind(provider='sqlite',
           filename=(r'D:\pythons\trainers-salaries-calculator' 
                     r'\trainers_salaries_calculator.sqlite'),
                     create_db=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using pyinstaller, add attribute --hidden-import pony.orm.dbproviders, when compiling, like so:
pyinstaller --hidden-import pony.orm.dbproviders your_script_path.py